# Unable to access ScalaFXML controller class members in another class

Tags: scala, scalafx, scalafxml

I have following code

```
@sfxml
class Charts(private val predicate_chart:ComboBox[String],
             private val measure_chart : ComboBox[String],
             private val chart_chart : ComboBox[String],
             private val chart_graph : ComboBox[String],
             private val chart_container:Pane) {

       val stackPane = new StackPane()

       def createCharts(): Unit ={    
            new KPie(this).createPie()
       }
}

class KPie(charts:Charts) {
     def createPieUI(result : ResultSet): Unit ={
           val qs: List[QuerySolution] = new IteratorResultSetQuerySolution(result).toList
           val pieChartData = ObservableBuffer(qs.map { v: QuerySolution => PieChart.Data(v.get("s").toString, v.getLiteral("measure").getDouble) })
           val chart = new PieChart(pieChartData)         
           charts.stackPane.getChildren.addAll(chart)
     }
}
```

while I am trying this I am getting following error

```
Error: value stackPane is not a member of Charts
    charts.stackPane.getChildren.addAll(chart)
```

I just want to use the controller class variables in another class. Please help me to access those member variables thanks in advance.

Comment: On the face of it, this is certainly odd. However, it's difficult to identify the cause from this small snippet. Can you please update your question to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to test that this resolves your issue, but the *ScalaFXML* [documentation](https://github.com/vigoo/scalafxml) indicates that the `@sfxml` macro replaces the controller class with a generated version, which effectively removes user-supplied class members. It looks like this is the explanation for your problem.

The documentation describes an approach to providing additional class members by placing them in a `trait` (or, possibly, an `abstract class`) from which your controller class is extended. To access these members, you first need to get a reference to the controller by calling `getController[Trait]` (where `Trait` is the name of the trait) on your `FXMLLoader` instance. Following this approach, your code would look something like this:

```scala
trait ChartsMembers {

  // Note: This stack pane is not apparently used anywhere.
  val stackPane = new StackPane()

  // Note: I added the ResultSet argument which is needed for your example.
  def createCharts(result: ResultSet): Unit = {

    // Note: There was no createPie() member of KPie in your example. I'm assuming that the
    // createPieUI(ResultSet) function was the original intended call. Here's what I did:
    // 1. Renamed createPie to createPieUI.
    // 2. Added the ChartsMembers reference, so that this trait's members are available.
    //
    // Note: The reference to the KPie instance was neither stored nor returned, and so would
    // be garbage collected. Since its charts argument is now redundant, I changed KPie to
    // be an object.
    KPie.createPieUI(this, result)
  }
}

// Note: Charts now extends ChartsMembers.
//
// Note: I have removed the "private val" declarations for the arguments, since they are
// redundant.
@sfxml
class Charts(
  predicate_chart: ComboBox[String],
  measure_chart: ComboBox[String],
  chart_chart: ComboBox[String],
  chart_graph: ComboBox[String],
  chart_container: Pane
) extends ChartsMembers

// Note: This is now an object - see note above.
object KPie {

  // Note: Changed signature - see note above.
  def createPieUI(controller: ChartsMembers, result: ResultSet): Unit = {
    val qs: List[QuerySolution] = new IteratorResultSetQuerySolution(result).toList
    val pieChartData = ObservableBuffer(qs.map { v: QuerySolution => 
      PieChart.Data(v.get("s").toString, v.getLiteral("measure").getDouble)
    })
    val chart = new PieChart(pieChartData)

    // Access the stackPane member on the controller.
    controller.stackPane.getChildren.addAll(chart)
  }
}
```

In order to use the above, you would first need to get a loader reference (which you will need in any case), and you would then use that to call the `createCharts` function:

```scala
val result = // As required...
val loader = new FXMLLoader(/*Args as required...*/)
val controller = loader.getReference[ChartsMembers]

// Create the charts on the controller.
controller.createCharts(result)
```

To be honest, this all seems rather convoluted, and the resulting populated stack pane isn't used by anything or added to the scene graph, so the above is all fairly pointless. However, I hope you can see how this approach works, so that you can implement it in your application.

A [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (including all source files and build files) would have helped immensely.